# Check in console if a specified site is "installed" in the IIS service

Tags: iis, console, soap

I have posted a question about how to check if web service is installed, but I have realized this is not I am looking for.

There is the next case - on Windows machine is installed the IIS. 
That service hosts 2 sites - 
`http://localhost/site1` and 
`http://localhost/site2` (just an example) that represent soap endpoints.

How can I check if there is installed site2 having only ssh access ?

**UPDATE**

To specify this case:

I am automating a test script.

In this script soap web services are checked.

One of test steps is to check if SOAP endpoint is installed on target machine.

After that I should try the connectivity to this end-point (this is not a problem, it's implemented in Java already)

So, using anything,but HTTP connection, I should check if this SOAP "site" is installed on machine.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that it's SSH access that you have?  That's very rare on a windows box.  To manage IIS, you generally use IIS Manager if you were given access, or for a shared hosting situation, it's common for them to give FTP access and then allow you to manage the site settings using their control panel.

Can you provide further information on what you can see now?  For example, do you see the site structure with the files, or do you see something different?

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: Using HTTP is by far the easiest and more consistent way to confirm that the endpoint is functioning correctly. Confirm that you get valid content from a test. Testing with SSH access will require confirming that IIS is working, that the app pool is started, possibly checking that permissions are correct, and confirming that the site content exists in the correct path. Even that doesn't fully test everything. So, this really depends on what level of testing you need to feel confident that it works correctly. I would recommend doing what you can to update your test to an http test if possible.

Comment: Yep, I agree, in this case it's easier to update the test script. I thought there is any simple way within cmd. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to Powershell you can use the  [**IIS admin cmdlets**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790599.aspx).

Possibly:

- Get-WebApplication
- Get-WebVirtualDirectory

Depends on your config as to what you can use.

Comment: Yep, is possible, but not so simple. I should in this case write a powershell script, upload it to server and so on... But anyway thank you for your answer :)